# Mudar cor do overflow button

Tags: android, cores

Gostaria de saber como faz principalmente para mudar a cor do overflow button, se o mesmo não for possível, mudar a imagem, para SDK minima 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660) no SOen, você pode alterar a cor do `Overflow Button` assim:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Ou, caso esteja usando a `ActionBarSherlock`:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

---

Ainda [na mesma pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425660) existem outras respostas que podem também serem úteis.

Comment: Mas diz que     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>     só pode ser usado na API 11 ou superior e preciso rodar em API 10

Comment: Está assim: `<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    </style>`

Comment: Descobri, para casos de api's anteriores a 21 usar `<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>`